# How to define a C++ concept that checks if a given template type parameter is a sequential container of pair<T, T>

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts, c++-templates

How can I define C++ `concept` that checks if a given template type parameter is a **sequential container or a range, of pairs** (e.g. `vector<pair<string, string>>`.

Let's say the name of the `concept` is `KeyValueContainer`. I need to be able to do this:

```
template <KeyValueContainer KVC_T>
void foo(KVC_T kvc)
{
    for(const auto [key, value]: kvc)
        // do stuff with key and value
}
```

P.S. By sequential container or range of pairs I mean a container or a range filled with pairs (`{pair1, pair2, pair3, ...}`)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you do it using a specialized template? If so, then making it a concept would be quite trivial.

Comment: Does it specifically have to be a "container"? Can it be a range instead? Also, does it need to be a range of *any* `pair`, or of a specific `pair` type?

Comment: Yes, It can be a range as well. But I need it to be a container of pairs. Because I make me capable of passing key-value of pairs around. e.g. function inputs, constructor inputs, similar to JSON key-value pairs.

Comment: @AskrAskr: You misunderstood. Does your function expect `pair<std::string, std::string>` (or some other specific type) or is it expected to work with *any* class generated from the `std::pair` template, so long as the two parameters are the same?

Comment: Also, if you're expecting to be able to shove the `pair`s from, say `std::map`, that's not going to work. A `map<T, T>` has the pair type `pair<const T, T>`. Those two are not the same type.

Comment: Do you really need the two template parameters to be the same? Or do you just want a range of tuple-like types of size 2?

Comment: "*sequential container or range of pairs*" Sequential container and range are different things, sequential container is always range and comes with more requirements. So what do you want is a sequential container or a generalized range concept?

Comment: No. My function expects a container or a range of `pair<T, T>`. In the function I iterate over the pairs with `for (auto [key, value]: container)`. Sometimes `T` is of another type and a custom functor converts it to another type. The point is that the container/range should be iterated over, so `key`, `value` pairs could be used. One example is for being inserted in a `map`. Another is `vector<pair<string,string>>` can be used as a collection of database connection handshake parameters.

Comment: Corrected some misunderstandings in the question

Comment: @AskrAskr: Do you mean `pair<T, T>` (which means *the same type* in both template parameters) or `pair<T, U>` (which allows for *different types*)? Because if it's the first one, you *cannot* use that with `map`, because its pairs are *not the same type*. `T` and `T const` are not the same type.

Comment: @NicolBolas you can copy such a sequence into a `map<T, T>`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can write a concept that matches `std::pair<T, T>` for all `T` directly, but you can write that as a trait.

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_homogenous_pair_v = false;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_homogenous_pair_v<std::pair<T, T>> = true;

template <typename T>
concept homogenous_pair = is_homogenous_pair_v<T>;

template <typename T>
concept KeyValueContainer = std::ranges::range<T> && homogenous_pair<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>;
```

If you want to allow anything tuple-like with 2 elements, you can instead have:

```
template <typename T>
concept homogenous_pair = (std::tuple_size_v<T> == 2) && std::same_as<std::tuple_element_t<0, T>, std::tuple_element_t<1, T>>;

template <typename T>
concept KeyValueContainer = std::ranges::range<T> && homogenous_pair<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>;
```

Comment: Would be a big bonus to support all tuple-like types too (but that requires some work on OP's side).

Comment: Pro-tip: `is_homogenous_pair` should be a variable template, not a class template. Will compile faster (and is less typing).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this much more easily by expanding your requirements so that they work for tuple-like type using the `get<0>` interface:

```
template<typename T>
concept RangePairs =
    ranges::range<T> &&
    std::tuple_size_v<ranges::range_value_t<T>> == 2 &&
    requires(ranges::range_value_t<T> t)
    {
        std::get<0>(t);
        std::get<1>(t);
        requires std::same_as<decltype(std::get<0>(t)), decltype(std::get<1>(t))>;
    };
```

`pair` is a tuple-like type, so it works. This of course requires that you use `get` internally to access the members instead of `first` and `second`.

Note however that this requires that the two internal types are *exactly* the same type. The sequence you get from a `map<T, T>` uses `pair<T const, T>` so it would not fit this requirement. As [shown here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vr6e88K85).

If you want this to work for any tuple-like type of `T` and `U` (that is, the two types don't *have* to be the same), then simply remove the `same_as` check from the above. Then it can work on `map`.

Comment: Technically this allows ranges of `pair<T, T&>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that [`ranges::keys_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/keys_view) and `ranges::values_view` have the same value type:

```
std::same_as<
    std::ranges::range_value_t<std::ranges::keys_view<R>>, 
    std::ranges::range_value_t<std::ranges::values_view<R>>>
```

Since you are using structured binding, you should also check that the range value has exactly 2 elements:

```
template<class R>
concept KeyValueContainer =
    std::same_as<
        std::ranges::range_value_t<std::ranges::keys_view<R>>, 
        std::ranges::range_value_t<std::ranges::values_view<R>>> and
    (std::tuple_size_v<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>> == 2);
```

Comment: Technically this allows ranges of `pair<T, T&>` and `pair<T, T const&>` and `pair<T, T&&>`.

Comment: Yes, which could well be what they want - this is why we have `range_value`, after all.

Comment: Could very well be, there's a comment asking for clarification.