# Variadic Template Argument Function with Concepts Failed to be Invoked

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts, c++-templates

I needed a function that can accept variable no. of arguments. Each one, a pair of the same type. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77083054/how-to-define-a-c-concept-that-checks-if-a-given-template-type-parameter-is-a) to define the concept.
With the following definition of variadic template argument function, I get 'no matching function for call' error.

```
template <typename T>
struct is_homogeneous_pair : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_homogeneous_pair<std::pair<T, T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
concept homogeneous_pair_c = is_homogeneous_pair<T>::value;

template <homogeneous_pair_c T1, homogeneous_pair_c... Tn>
void echo_kvp(T1 pair1, Tn... pairpack)
{
    std::cout << std::format("{} ==> {}", pair1.first, pair1.second) << std::endl;
    if (sizeof...(pairpack) == 0)
        return;
    echo_kvp(pairpack...);
}
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace std::literals;
echo_kvp(pair{"username"s, "root"s}, pair{"dbname"s, "info"s});
echo_kvp(pair{1, 2}, pair{4, 5});
```

Despite the fact that arguments passed to the function satisfy the `homogeneous_pair_c` concept, I still get the error: no matching function for call.
How can I make the function capable of accepting variable no. of arguments that satisfy the `homogeneous_pair_c` concept?
The above definition doesn't even work with `echo_kvp(pair{1, 2})`.

Here's the picture of the code in CLion.
[image: code in clion]
Thanks.

Comment: typo for the pair, and missing `constexpr` for the `if`, then it compiles [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7EEj5Ef8G).

Comment: `echo_kvp(pairpack...);` is not protected inside a `if constexpr (sizeof...(pairpack) != 0)`.

Comment: Fold expression might avoid the recursion BTW: `((std::cout << std::format("{} ==> {}", pairpack.first, pairpack.second) << std::endl), ...);`.

Comment: @BoP sorry, missed the trailing `s` when I was I was copying. fixed it, also fixed `constexpr`, but still doesn't work.

Comment: You still miss the `else`. You have issue with "ill formed" unreachable code...

Comment: @Jarod42 Do all `if constexpr`s need `else` ?

Comment: Thanks @BoP, your solution works. But what if I don't want to use fold expressions?

Comment: Do you read demo link I provided?

Comment: @Jarod42 Just did. It works. Thanks. But why would I need to add the `else`? if the `if constexpr` condition is not satisfied, it should execute `echo_kvp(pairpack...);` without `else`.

Comment: Your code becomes mostly `void f(T , Ts... ts) { return; f(ts...); }`. Even if unreachable code, it should be valid.

Comment: @Jarod42, So you're saying it'd be valid, but it's not. I just removed the keyword `else`, it 's not working. Doesn't even compile. If I add the keyword `else` to the same condition (same code in the picture, but with `else` keyword), it works. How does adding a single `else` fix the problem?

Comment: I meant, `f(ts...);` should be valid to compile (even if unreachable), whereas it is not for empty pack.